# Any automated way to notify GitHub PR Author when required status check fails?

Tags: github, groovy, automation, continuous-integration, pull-request

In our company's GitHub org/repo, the PRs "*require status checks to pass before merging*". Status check like Gearset CI job, codescan run etc.

[image: Example of required status check setting in branch protection.]

We are planning to enable "**Allow Auto-Merge**" feature in our GitHub repo. We are advertising this feature to our team as - "*You can create the PR, click 'Enable Auto-Merge' button and leave. You don't have to babysit it.*" This works fine if all required status checks pass. But if any of them fail, that's a problem. Developers won't know their PR is stuck until hours later when they manually come back to check.

[image: Example of failed status checks in a PR]

So my question is - Is there any automated way to notify the PR author when any required status checks fail? Right now, the author automatically gets an email in these events -

- when reviewer approves the PR,
- when anyone leaves a comment on the PR,
- when the PR gets closed.
- when the PR gets merged.

Is there a configuration available anywhere so that they will get email (or slack msg) automatically if their PR's required status check fails?

Also, is there any GitHub webhook event for the same that can trigger a workflow? So that whenever a status check fails, it'll trigger a job in Jenkins. I checked the "[Status](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#status)" activity documentation, but doesn't look like that's for PR's status check. Any ideas?

## What I already tried

I checked in https://github.com/settings/notifications but there's no option for failed required status checks there.

Google search results say it can be done using GitHub Actions, but GHA are disabled in our org.

I tried to create a Jenkins pipeline using GitHub webhook as trigger, just to check if the trigger works -

```
pipeline {
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    triggers {
        eventTrigger jmespathQuery("provider=='github' && eventName=='status' && webhook.state=='failure' && webhook.context='Gearset 3. uat to UAT Deploy' && webhook.repository.name=='sfdc'")
    }
    agent { agent details here. }
    stages {
        stage('PR Status Checker') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def causes = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0]['event']
                    println "Causes: " + causes
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this jenkins job didn't trigger at all. (In contrast, eventName=="pull_request" pipelines trigger fine.)

Comment: At https://github.com/settings/notifications, users can configure their notifications to get push notifications in GitHub, or an email when a workflow fails. This is less precise than what you ask for, but requires zero development work.

Comment: Also, the webhook event for a status is [`status`](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#status).

Comment: I had already checked https://github.com/settings/notifications. The "notify for failed workflows" is only for "workflow runs on repositories set up with GitHub Actions". In my org, GitHub actions are disabled. So, I can't use that. 

In the Subscriptions -> "Customize email updates" section, there's option only for "Pull request reviews" , "pull request pushes", "Comment on issues and pull requests" and "includes your own updates". 

I already did try the eventName=='status' in my jenkins pipeline attempt. That did not trigger the pipeline. :(

See "What I already tried" section in OP.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is comment on the Github PR, in case of a failure with tagging the PR author that your pipeline has failed, I have applied this using Github Actions which is quite simple, but I am pretty sure it can be done using Jenkins as well, either using any plugin or using Github API yourself..

An example of the comment on PR
https://github.com/kahootali/golang-sample-app/pull/38#issuecomment-1279916092

Comment: I can write a script to do the commenting and tagging the author in it. this script needs to run when any status check fails. But problem is - how do I automatically detect that status check has failed?

Comment: cant you add them as part of your status check jobs? if they fail, you can add the step to comment on PR

Comment: I can add commenting step to 2 of the status checks that I've built myself. The other two are 3rd party status checks - Gearset and Codescan. Those don't have any option of adding a comment to the PR in case of failure.